# Angular 10 mat-table onClick Scroll to top of table

Tags: angular

Using Angular 10, I have a mat-table that scrolls. At the bottom of the scrollable table is a link that when clicked I would like to have it scroll to the top of the table. What's the code to have it move the scrollbar to the top. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell `ViewChild` which token you want to read from the selector. In your case that would be `ElementRef`, by passing a second parameter in the form of `{ read: ElementRef }`.

```
@ViewChild('table', {read: ElementRef}) table: ElementRef;
```

Comment: i can get the table, but then what? I tried this matTable.scrollTop = 0; but didnt work.